# Complex integral $ \int_{\partial D_R} \frac{\exp\bigr( \pi i (z - 1/2)^2 \bigl)}{1 - \exp(-2\pi i z)} \mathrm{d}z $

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I have been working on the following problem from Gamelin VII.1 problem 6.

> Consider the integral
>   $$   J = \int_{\partial D_R} \frac{\exp\bigr(
>   \pi i (z - 1/2)^2 \bigl)}{1 - \exp(-2\pi i z)}    \mathrm{d}z $$
>   where $D_R$ is the parallelogram with $\pm \frac12 \pm (1+i) R$.
>
> **a)** Use the residue theorem to shot that the integral is $(1+i)/\sqrt2$.
>
> **b)** By parameterizing the sides of the parallelogram, show that the integral  tends to  $$   (1+i) \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2 \pi t^2}
> > \mathrm{d}t $$ as $R \to \infty$.
>
> **c)** Use **a)** and **c)** to show that $$   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \,\mathrm{d}s = \sqrt{\pi} $$

I have been able to solve **a)** using the residue theorem. No matter what 
$R$ is, the only singularity will be located at $z=0$. So

[image: The contour integral]

$$
J = 2\pi i \cdot \text{Res}\left[ \frac{\exp\bigr(
  \pi i (z - 1/2)^2 \bigl)}{1 - \exp(-2\pi i z)}  , z=0\right]
  = 2\pi i \left[ \frac{\exp\bigr(
  \pi i (0 - 1/2)^2 \bigl)}{2 i \pi \exp(-2\pi i \cdot 0)} \right]
  = e^{\pi i/4}
$$

Which is the same as $(1+i)/\sqrt{2}$.

*Now my problem lies in showing* **b)**.
*In particular how do I prove that the integrals over $\gamma_4$ and $\gamma_2$
tends to zero as $R \to \infty$?*

Answer (score 2):

Note that on these segments, $\arg(z)$ gets closer to $\pi/4$ and $5\pi/4$. Thus, the $\arg(z^2)$ approaches $\pi/2$ in both cases.  Thus,
$$
\pi i(z-1/2)^2\text{ approaches }-\pi|z|^2\sim-2\pi R^2
$$
The denominator stays away from $\mathbb{R}$ which is the only place that the it can vanish. That is, on the segment in the first quadrant, the denominator has absolute value about $e^{2\pi R}$ and in the third quadrant, the denominator has absolute value approaching $1$.

Comment: Could you say that along the top of the parallelogram,

$$ \text{max} \ \Big|\exp \left(\pi i \left( z-1/2\right)^{2} \right) \Big|= \text{max} \ \Big| \text{exp} \left( \pi i \left( t+R+iR - 1/2 \right)^{2} \right)\Big|  $$

$$ = \text{max} \ e^{-2 \pi R^{2}} e^{-2 \pi Rt} e^{\pi R} = e^{-2 \pi R^{2}} e^{2 \pi R}$$

And 

$$ \text{min} \ |1-e^{-2 \pi i z}|  = e^{2 \pi R }-1$$

Then the magnitude of the integral along the top of the parallelogram is bounded from above by $$ 1 \times \frac{e^{-2 \pi R^{2}}}{1-e^{-2 \pi R}} \to 0  \ \text{as} \ R \to \infty \ ?$$

Comment: @RandomVariable: the estimate would go something like that. I think the first estimate would be $e^{-2\pi R^2+\pi R}$, but the difference is irrelevant to the answer.

Comment: The reason I have $e^{2 \pi R}$ is because on the interval $-\frac{1}{2} \le t \le \frac{1}{2}$, $e^{-2 \pi R t}$ is maximized when $t = -\frac{1}{2}$. Then $\text{max} \ e^{-2 \pi R^{2}} e^{-2 \pi Rt} e^{\pi R} =  e^{-2 \pi Rt} e^{\pi R} e^{\pi R} = e^{-2 \pi R^{2}} e^{2 \pi R} $.

Comment: $$\begin{align}\mathrm{Re}\left(\pi i\left(t-\tfrac12+R(1+i)\right)^2\right) &=\mathrm{Re}\left(-2\pi R^2+2\pi iR(1+i)\left(t-\tfrac12\right)+\pi i\left(t-\tfrac12\right)^2\right)\\ &=-2\pi R^2-2\pi R\left(t-\tfrac12\right)\end{align}$$ which is greatest when $t=0$: $-2\pi R^2+\pi R$

Comment: The variable $t$ is varying from $- \frac{1}{2}$ to $\frac{1}{2}$, right? $-\frac{1}{2}$  And when $t=-\frac{1}{2}$, we have $\exp( -2 \pi R^{2} + 2 \pi R)$.  That's larger than $\exp(-2 \pi R^{2} + \pi R)$, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, I thought that $t-\frac12\in[-\frac12,\frac12]$, but I see that $t\in[-\frac12,\frac12]$. In that case, the maximum would occur when $t=-\frac12$ and we would indeed get $-2\pi R^2+2\pi R$. However, as I said before, this difference is irrelevant to the answer.